# Restangular Order by : AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sql-order-by, restangular

I'm using Restangular for fetching data from my NodeJs Api. I'm stuck where I need to fetch and display values to my client view in **recently added order**

Here is the code for fetching list from api

```
$scope.blogs = Blog.getList().$object;
```

I wanted to know what is the code for fetching the list in a **order by** manner specified.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of displaying the data in an ordered fashion.

1. You can use the [order by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) expression in the angular template
2. If you want to fetch the data from the API in an ordered list:

   - Your API must accept some sort of parameter / know how to order
   - The order parameter is sent to the API in the getList call

The following shows an example of sending parameters:

```
$scope.blogs = Blog.getList({
    sort: 'sortSyntax'
}).$object;
```

3. Manually sort the list of items after it is fetched

Like this:

```
Blog.getList().then(function (blogs) {
    $scope.blogs = _.sortBy(blogs, 'dateAdded');
});
```